# Unable to compare SQL and datatable and copy new entries to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I try to run a Left Join on my SQL Server 2012 database in VB.NET and I am stuck with this piece of code:

```
Dim dtTabelle1 as DataTable
(first Column of dtTabelle1 = Zyklus ID)

Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim conString, cmdString As String
Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand

conString = "path"
con = New SqlConnection(conString)
con.Open()

dtTabelle1.TableName = "Test"

cmdString = "INSERT INTO Daten ([Zyklus ID])" & _
                "Select [Zyklus ID]" & _
                "FROM Test " & _
                "LEFT JOIN Daten ON (Test.[Zyklus ID] = Daten.[Zyklus ID])" & _
                    "WHERE (Daten.[Zyklus ID] IS NULL);"

cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdString, con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

I get an error:

> Invalid Object name 'Test'

(Btw I can't change the blank in "Zyklus ID" :( ).

`dtTabelle1` is filled and the schema is identical with the target database on the server `Daten`.

Comment: under what schema is table Test? under "default" dbo or different?

Comment: the schema is default

Comment: one more question: is the target database for the script the correct one? Side note: always try to prefix the table name with the schemaName. (i.e reference table as SchemaName.TableName)

Comment: how would that look like? default.Test?

Comment: no, it would look like dbo.Test. I was referring as "default" for dbo schema.

Comment: just to make sure they both have the same schema, how can i check if my datatabel schema? when i filled my DataTable test in the beginning i used : adp.FillSchema(Test, SchemaType.Mapped)
adp.Fill(Test) (connected to a .mdb file)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if You Use **Alias** For Table

Try like this:

```
cmdString = "INSERT INTO Daten ([Zyklus ID])" & _
                "Select T.[Zyklus ID]" & _
                "FROM Test T " & _
                "LEFT JOIN Daten D ON (T.[Zyklus ID] = D.[Zyklus ID])" & _
                    "WHERE (D.[Zyklus ID] IS NULL);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put the appropriate spaces between the SQL statements of your query

```
cmdString = "INSERT INTO Daten ([Zyklus ID]) " & _
            "SELECT [Zyklus ID] " & _
            "FROM Test " & _
            "LEFT JOIN Daten ON (Test.[Zyklus ID] = Daten.[Zyklus ID]) " & _
            "WHERE (Daten.[Zyklus ID] IS NULL);"
```